# Search Pattern Error since Google Scripts V8 Update

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, v8

Ever since google forced the update "This project is running on our new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8." I'm getting the following error and I don't understand why.

"Exception: Invalid argument: searchPattern at recreateReferral(recreateReferral:82:13)"

Here is the snippet of code:  Line 82 starts with newBody.

```
for(i = 0; i <=16; i++) {
newBody.replaceText(fields[0][i], newData[0][i]);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `fields[0][i]`?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: There appear to be some issues regarding this type of error but to be honest the reports aren't very specific and I suspect they'll be hard to reproduce so it might be best to report it as an issue but please provide them with a lot more information than you provided to us.  [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B)  [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible cause(s):

- Your original rhino script is buggy, because it doesn't check the type of the argument `fields[0][i]` and `newData[0][i]`.
- Empty string `""` and `null` also throw this error.

#### Solution:

- Cast type and check length of the argument before feeding it to `replaceText()`

#### Snippet:

```
if (String(fields[0][i]).length){
  newBody.replaceText(String(fields[0][i]), String(newData[0][i]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I had a feeling that you would be able to provide some insight here.

Comment: @Cooper I'm still not sure about this as this isn't a `Type error`.So, take the solution with caution.

Comment: @Cooper I think I found it. Tested and confirmed that It happens mainly due to empty strings. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It was the empty parts of the string as someone above suggested.

Thanks!